# Copy and Merge files to another S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a source bucket where small 5KB JSON files will be inserted every second.
I want to use AWS Athena to query the files by using an AWS Glue Datasource and crawler.
For better query performance AWS Athena recommends [larger file sizes](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/).

So I want to copy the files from the source bucket to bucket2 and merge them.

I am planning to use S3 events to put a message in AWS SQS for each file created, then a lambda will be invoked with a batch of x sqs messages, read the data in those files, combine and save them to the destination bucket. bucket2 then will be the source of the AWS Glue crawler.

Will this be the best approach or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of receiving 5KB JSON file every second in Amazon S3, the best situation would be to receive this data via [Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/what-is-this-service.html), which can **automatically combine data based on either size or time period**. It would output fewer, larger files.

You could also achieve this with a **slight change** to your current setup:

- When a file is uploaded to S3, trigger an AWS Lambda function
- The Lambda function reads the file and send it to Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose
- Kinesis Firehose then batches the data by size or time

Alternatively, you could use Amazon Athena to read data from multiple S3 objects and output them into a new table that uses **Snappy-compressed Parquet files**. This file format is very efficient for querying. However, your issue is that the files are arriving every second so it is difficult to query the incoming files in batches (so you know which files have been loaded and which ones have *not* been loaded). A kludge could be a script that does the following:

- Create an external table in Athena that points to a batching directory (eg `batch/`)
- Create an external table in Athena that points to the final data (eg `final/`)
- Have incoming files come into `incoming/`
- At regular intervals, trigger a Lambda function that will list the objects in `incoming/`, copy them to `batch/` and delete those source objects from `incoming/` (any objects that arrive during this copy process will be left for the next batch)
- In Athena, run `INSERT INTO final SELECT * FROM batch`
- Delete the contents of the `batch/` directory

This will append the data into the `final` table in Athena, in a format that is good for querying.

However, the Kinesis Firehose option is simpler, even if you need to trigger Lambda to send the files to the Firehose.

Comment: Thanks. I did have a look at AWS Kinesis Firehose. I just have to figure out the best approach to passing my data (StepFunction Output) to Kinesis FIrehose. I can create a lambda to post to Kinesis Firehose directly using its API or EventBridge -> Kinesis Datastream -> Kinesis Firehose

Answer (score 0):

You can probably achive that using glue itself. Have a look here https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-glue-samples/blob/master/examples/join_and_relationalize.md

Comment: Thanks for this. This will require me to keep track of all the newly received files.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think will be more simpler

1. Have input folder `input/` let 5kb/ 1kb files land here; `/data` we will use this to have Json files with max size of 200MB.
2. Have a lambda that runs every 1minute which reads a set of files from `input/` and appends to the last file in the folder `/data` using golang/ java.
3. The lambda (with max concurrency as 1) copies a set of 5kb files from `input/` and the `XMB` files from `data/` folder into its `/tmp` folder; and merge them and then upload the merged file to `/data` and also delte the files from `input/` folder
4. When ever the file size crosses `200MB` create a new file into `data/` folder

The advantage here is at any instant if somebody wants data its the union of `input/` and `data/` folder or in other words

With little tweeks here and there you can expose a view on top of `input` and `data` folders which can expose final de-duplicated snapshot of the final data.